# Use v-model instead of name attribute for Vee-Validate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I recently started learning to build a SPA with Vue and today i'm looking into Vee-Validate.

With Vee-Validate, the validation needs the `name` attribute to be filled. If not, we get the following warning: `[vee-validate] A field is missing a "name" or "data-vv-name" attribute`.

That's ok but i feel it's a little bit redundant to fill this attribute since i'm not using it at all. I get what the user entered with `v-model` and i send it to the server with an ajax post request. Having to fill this attribute give me this kind of tag: `<input name="firstname" v-model="firstname" v-validate="'required'" />`, where the `name="firstname"` is only usefull to Vee-Validate.

With all this in mind, is there a way to tell Vee-Validate to use the `v-model` instead of the `name` attribute? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as is not possible, the `name` or `data-vv-name` attribute contains a string that is used as input to generate error messages and is the attribute on which the library is based to customize error messages, for example i18n support.